# Minimise the probability of a variable being positive?

Tags: probability, optimization

So the problem statement is that we are given that ($v^Ts$ is the variance)
$$x \sim \mathcal{N}(v^Tc,v^Ts)$$
Where $c,s$ are constants and $v^Tv=1$. Show that minimising $\mathbb{P}(x>0)$ with respect to $v$ is equivalent to minimising $\frac{v^Tc}{\sqrt{v^Ts}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In order to minimize $P(x > 0)$ you want the mean of your Gaussian to be as many standard deviations above zero as possible. That's exactly the interpretation of the second quantity you mentioned in terms of $v,c,s$.

Comment: I'm an idiot - wrote the whole Lagrangian and took derivatives... when setting $z = x - \frac{v^Tc}{\sqrt{v^Ts}}$ e.g. transform to standard normal is sufficient to prove this. Thanks for the hint reminds me again why I shouldn't do too much analysis.